# Modular Exponentiation with 8 digit numbers

Tags: java, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

A Java program to find the result of raising a large number to a power over a modulus does not appear to work when the base of the exponent is 8 digits or greater.

Bases that have 8 or more digits do not work (checked against online modular exponentiation calculator).

```
public static int modExp(int b, int e, int m){
    System.out.println(b);
    int c = 1;
    int e2 = 0;
    while(e2<e){
        e2++;
        c = (b*c)%m;
    }
    if(c<0){
        c += m;
    }
    return c;
}
```

for `e = 5` and `m = 437`

`11111111` (8 digits) returns `35` while the online calculator returns `233`.

`12345678` (8 digits) returns `224` while the calculator returns `383`.

`1234567` (7 digits), works.

Comment: `b*c` is overflowing in some cases - for example, when `b` is 11111111, any `c` value over 193 overflows.  Either reduce `b` modulo `m` to start with (so you're never dealing with large numbers), or use `long` instead of `int` for your intermediate results.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Reducing modulo `m` first is not permanent solution, because `m` might have 8 digits itself, allowing both `b` and `c` to have 8 digits as well, and then their product would have about 16 digits which doesn't fit. Using `long` is fine.